# tensorflow 1.5 and cuda 9 can't run model correctly

Tags: tensorflow

I have a model write in `tensorflow 1.4` and `cuda-8.0`. The model can run correctly without any error. But when I updated the cuda to `cuda 9.0` and tensorflow to `tensorflow 1.5` I can't run the model. When I run the model, the code stoped and show nothing, for a long time the code exit and reported the following message `interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL`. How to run the code using `cuda 9` and `tensorflow 1.5`?

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: The code seems stop running at `sess.run(xxx)`, and waiting for a long time the code exit running and the console only outputs `interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL` .

Comment: Perhaps you can try adding more logging (using tf.Print or tf.logging) to help debug this problem.